# Why is this ArrayList throwing a ConcurrentModificationException when I try to remove an element?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, iterator

I'm trying to remove a particular element from Arraylist, it throws an ConcurrentModificationException

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ar.add("a");
ar.add("b");
ar.add("c");
ar.add("a");
ar.add("e");
for(String st: ar){
    System.out.println("st="+st);
    if(st.equals("a")){
        ar.remove(st);
    }
}
```

any comments, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only remove an element from the array while iterating by using `Iterator.remove()`.**

The line `for(String st: ar) {` is a bit misleading.  You're actually creating an iterator behind the scenes which is being used for this iteration.  If you need to remove elements from within the iteration, you need to explicitly use an iterator so that you can call `iterator.remove()`.

```
ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
ar.add("a");
ar.add("b");
ar.add("c");
ar.add("a");
ar.add("e");
Iterator<String> it = ar.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String st = it.next();
    System.out.println("st="+st);
    if (st.equals("a")) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you would also have to use `Iterator.remove()` to delete an element from an `ArrayList` while using `ArrayList.forEach()`?

Answer (score 0):

You're removing an element from a collection while you're iterating over that collection, without using the iterator to do it. Don't do that. There are lots of alternatives, primarily:

- Use indexes instead (`get`, `remove(int)`) being careful about your counts so that you don't skip over items

  ```
     for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
         String st = ar.get(i);
         System.out.println("st="+st);
         if(st.equals("a")) {
             ar.remove(i);
             i--; // We want to use this index again
         }
     }
  ```
- Build up a collection of items to remove, then remove them all afterwards

  ```
    List<String> elementsToRemove = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String st: ar){
        System.out.println("st="+st);
        if(st.equals("a")){
            elementsToRemove.add(st);
        }
    }
    ar.removeAll(elementsToRemove);
  ```
- Remove using the iterator, if the iterator supports removal (as `ArrayList`'s does)

  ```
    for (Iterator<String> it = ar.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String st = it.next();
        System.out.println("st="+st);
        if(st.equals("a")) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you are modifing the array you are iterating on.
I suggest you to use the Iterator to do similar things.

Comment: thank you for the specification. A novice like me learns from the comments as well :)

Comment: @SteveKuo For-each does use an iterator but it is not possible to call its `remove()` method, so what maVVamaldo said is good advice if it is interpreted as "use **an explicit** operator", since that would allow safe deletion via `Iterator.remove()`.