# ConcurrentModificationException when deleting an element from ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

Java is throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` when I am running the following code. Any idea why is that?

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Hello");
list1.add("World");
list1.add("Good Evening");

for (String s : list1){
        list1.remove(2);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException for ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184883/concurrentmodificationexception-for-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at documentation of [ConcurrentModificationException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) you will find that

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
>   modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>
> For example, **it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify
>   a Collection while another thread is iterating over it**
>
> ...
>
> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread
>   issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
>   an object, the object may throw this exception. **For example, if a
>   thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
>   collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this
>   exception**.

Important thing about this exception is that we can't guarantee it will always be thrown as stated in documentation

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally
>   speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of
>   unsynchronized concurrent modification. ***Fail-fast* operations throw
>   `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis**.

Also from [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator`
>   methods are ***fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`**.

(emphasis mine)

So you can't manipulate content of Collection (in your case List) while iterating over it via enhanced for loop because you are not doing it via iterator for-each is using internally.

To solve it just get your own `Iterator` and use it in your loop. To remove elements from collection use `remove` like in this example

```
Iterator<String> it = list1.iterator();
int i=0;
while(it.hasNext()){
    String s = it.next();
    i++;
    if (i==2){
        it.remove();
        System.out.println("removed: "+ s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the output its says "removed" for all items.

Comment: Erick is also giving similar explanation (though in a shorter format :) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469210/why-is-this-arraylist-throwing-a-concurrentmodificationexception-when-i-try-to-r?rq=1]

Comment: Yes, now that I've searched over SO for `ArrayList` and `ConcurrentModificationException` I found many questions with shorter answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete an item with `ArrayList`'s `remove()` method while iterating over it. Use `Iterator` if you want to delete the item also while iterating.

**But you are deleting an item based on index** then simply moving below line outside the loop will solve your problem.

```
 list1.remove(2);
```

Comment: i agree, it works with Iterator. But, why does not it give me an error when i add an if statement in the same loop. here is the code. for (String s : list1){
   
   if(s.equals("World")){
    list1.remove(1);
   }
   
  }

Comment: Try this one `for (String s : list1){ if(s.equals("Hello")){ list1.remove(1); } }` You can't delete an item that is not processed yet or you can say whose index is greater than current running index of for-each loop.

Comment: I am not sure but its a good question. Let me try to find out the exact reason.

Comment: @user3520698 As I pointed in my answer throwing this exception cannot be guaranteed. Fail-fast operations throw  ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. One of the reasons for this could be caching modification counter by threads (if you take a look at `modCount` in `ArrayList` class you will not see `volatile` modifier which could prevent this value from being cached).

Answer (score 0):

form the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) you can read

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent
>   modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.
>   For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify
>   a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general,
>   the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances.
>   Some Iterator implementations (including those of all the general
>   purpose collection implementations provided by the JRE) may choose to
>   throw this exception if this behavior is detected. Iterators that do
>   this are known as fail-fast iterators, as they fail quickly and
>   cleanly, rather that risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at
>   an undetermined time in the future.

further more, suppose that you can remove item 2 at each iteration. You will end up in a index out of bound exception:

- at first iteration you remove item #2 (`"Good evening"`) and list size become 1 (item 0 `"hello"` and item 1 `"World"`)
- at next iteration you remove item #2 which actually does not exist in your list. Your list is indeed of size two, but counter starts from 0, thus you end up removing something which is not there: this is an example of the non-deterministic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't iterating over an list after the underlying list is modified.if you do that its give you `ConcurrentModificationException`

to resolve this issue use `java.util.ListIterator`  for iteration of list.

```
    ListIterator<String> it = list1.listIterator();
    for (String s : list1) {
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            String item = it.next();
            System.out.println(item);
        }
        }
```