# Iterator related issue

Tags: java

I know that in ArrayList, the iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are fail-fast.

So if i write something like below. Since I am using List object to remove rather than using Iterator's remove so it throw's concurrentModification exception as in that case expectedModCount is not equal ModCount.

```
    List<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
    n.add("1");
    n.add("2");
    n.add("3");
    n.add("4");


    Iterator<String> i = n.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        String t = i.next();
        if(t.equals("4"))
            n.remove(t);
        System.out.println(t);

    }
```

But if you remove the second last element in the list, then the exception is not thrown.
I.e if you write (in the if statement, `t.remove("1")` or `t.remove("2")` or `t.remove("4")` ) it throws `concurrentModificationException`.But if I write `t.remove("3")`, then this exception is not thrown.

What could be the reason?

Comment: `t.remove("2")` ?? where `t` is a String ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23170607/1393766

Comment: @Pshemo An interesting question nevertheless :)

Comment: Thanks Florent for your incredible answer

Comment: Hey Florent, So can i say that flaw is in public boolean hasNext() { return cursor != size; }

Answer (score 0):

There is a field called modCount in AbstractList, that store the number of times this list has been structurally modified, and an inner class called Itr that implements Iterator created a variabled called expectedModCount which is initialized in the beginning with modCount. The concurrentModificationException is thrown when during iteration modCount!=expectedModCount 
Here is the code

```
    public void remove() {
        if (lastRet < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
            cursor = lastRet;
            lastRet = -1;
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without an explanation which covers the semantics of `modCount` and `expectedModCount` (among other things), this answer is useless.

Comment: Buddy i have gone through the arraylist code, but didn't get as this exception is caused when modCount and expectedModCount are unequal

Comment: It is not `remove` which throws exception, but `next`. Your answer is at least not complete.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i updated the answer is it more complete now